# Android: как проигрывать защищённые аудифайлы из интернета?

Tags: android, http, mediaplayer, download, android-mediaplayer

Есть база аудиофайлов объёмом больше гигабайта. Моё приложение позволяет выбрать любой файл из этой базы и проиграть его. Включать все аудиофайлы в приложение не хочется - приложение получится слишком тяжелым. Да и к тому же они могут обновляться. Есть мысль сделать сайт (HTTPS или FTP) и выложить эти аудиофайлы на сайт. И пусть приложение скачивает их оттуда.

Я знаю, что android.media.MediaPlayer позволяет проигрывать аудиофайлы с интернета по URL.

Но хочется, чтобы доступ к этим файлам был только у приложения, чтобы все желающие не могли скачивать и прослушивать эти файлы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это проще всего сделать?

В документации к MediaPlayer я не нашёл информации, как там например можно было бы указать имя пользователя и пароль для доступа к файлам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение (код на Kotlin):

```
    // Authdata
    val username = "login"
    val password = "password"

    // encrypt Authdata
    val toEncrypt = "$username:$password".toByteArray()
    val encoded = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT)

    // create header
    var headers: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    headers["Authorization"] = "Basic $encoded"

    var uri: Uri = Uri.parse("http://site.url")
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(this, uri, headers)
```